# How can I navigate one code hierarchy level up?

Tags: sublimetext3

Consider this rather common instance: you have a huge class, like so...

```
class SuperMegaAwesomeClass():
  # ...
    # several
      # hundred
      # lines
  # of
    # other code that's
      # uninteresting
      # irrelevant
  # later
    # ...
  def ReallyGoodMethodThatIsPreciselyWhatYouNeedRightNow(omg, yes):
    pass
```

...and if you use `Ctrl-Shift-R Really` you can jump straight to `ReallyGoodMethodThatIsPreciselyWhatYouNeedRightNow`. However, you now have to figure out how to get there, so you try and slowly and painfully scroll up so that you don't miss the single-line class header and maybe start realizing that people who want 4 spaces per indentation level in Python might after have been onto something, perhaps, maybe.

Anyway. Sublime Text already does code folding for most languages, so I suppose it's not outlandish to assume that it has one super mega awesome command that lets you jump right up one level of code folding. Right? Because I can't find it under `Ctrl-Shift-P`.

How can I jump up one level in Sublime Text?

Comment: +1 for your function definition :)

Comment: Cursor on the function, and `Ctrl-Shift-J`

Comment: Also close but not quite: for properly indented files, add `"indent_guide_options": ["draw_normal", "draw_active"]` to your user settings, then place your cursor anywhere and scroll up to the point where the pink dotted indentation guide becomes solid gray again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple Python plugin and keybinding to do this:

1. From the Tools menu, choose Developer -> New Plugin...
2. Replace the contents of the new tab with this:

   ```
   import sublime
   import sublime_plugin


   class GoUpAnIndentLevelCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
       def run(self, edit):
           region = self.view.indented_region(self.view.sel()[0].begin())
           self.view.sel().clear()
           self.view.sel().add(self.view.line(region.begin() - 1))
   ```
3. Save it, in the folder ST suggests, as something like `goupindentation.py`
4. In your user keybindings file, add something like this and save it:

   ```
   { "keys": ["alt+'"], "command": "go_up_an_indent_level" },
   ```